# he name "OpenGLControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF"

Tags: c#, .net, opengl, sharpgl

I have problem with openGL wrapper - SharpGL-> I am not able to build solution because of  missing assembly .

**The name "OpenGLControl" does not exist in the namespace "clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF"**

The requiered assemblies **are  all referenced**, also in object browser I can see whole content
I am using .NET 4.5.2 and  VS2013

```
<Window x:Class="sharpGLTEst.MainWindow"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        xmlns:my="clr-namespace:SharpGL.WPF;assembly=SharpGL.WPF"
        Title="MainWindow" Height="350" Width="525">
    <Grid>
        <sharpGL:OpenGLControl />
    </Grid>
</Window>
```

Answer (score 0):

the solution is to create control directly in  code

SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl op = new SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl();

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl op = new SharpGL.WPF.OpenGLControl();
            SharpGL.OpenGL gl = op.OpenGL;
            SharpGLControlPanel.Children.Add(op);
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

It is an old question, but since I ran into it recently I thought maybe others hit this too.

To fix this I changed the project Target .NetFramework to 4.0 instead of leaving the default value, which for a new project is typically the latest version.

Good luck!